# How to create a new fetch Response promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, fetch-api

I have a function similar to the code below - it makes a `fetch`, does things when the call is successful or not, and returns a promise to be handled downstream:

```
const myFunc = (): Response => {
  return fetch('http://something')
    .then(r => {
      console.log('the call went through, the return code does not matter')
      return r
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(`ah crap, the call failed completely: ${err}`)
        // and here I do not know how to return a new Response
      }
    }
}

myFunc().then(r => {
  console.log('do something once myFunc is over')
})
```

My intention is to run some code once `myFunc` is done, but I need to account for the case the call completely fails (no DNS resolution, rejected call, ...). For that I need to create and return in the `catch()` a `Response` promise with, for instance, a forced `503` return code (which is not really correct because the server did not even answer, but anyway).

My question: how can I create such a `Response` promise?

Comment: It's actually much simpler if you use `async` `await` and a common or garden `try{}catch{}` if you can

Comment: Why do you need to make a network failure look like an HTTP failure? Why not just let it look like what it is, a network failure?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: because I want to do something once the fetch is done (whether the call is successful or not will not matter for that "something", it just needs to be after the fetch (successful or not)).

Comment: you can `return Promise.reject(someObject);` in the catch so that callers see the promise fail.  `someObject` can be whatever you want the caller to see as the rejection value (including `err` if it makes sense). Then your caller can handle the promise rejection appropriately

Comment: @WoJ - You don't have to create a fake HTTP error to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would encourage you **not** to turn a network failure into an apparent HTTP failure (503), but since you've **specifically** asked how to do that, you can do that by building your own [`Response` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response):

```
const myFunc = (): Response => {
    return fetch("http://something")
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(`the call failed completely: ${err}`)
        return new Response(null, {
            status: 503,
            statusText: "Fake 503",
        }); 
    });
};
```

or if you want to use an `async` function:

```
const myFunc = async (): Response => {
    try {
        return await fetch("http://something");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`the call failed completely: ${err}`)
        return new Response(null, {
            status: 503,
            statusText: "Fake 503",
        }); 
    }
};
```

(Note that there's no need for your `.then` in the first one (unless you want to do the `console.log`).)

**But**, I would strongly encourage you **not** to do that. Instead, handle this at the point of the call, via a `.finally` handler (or a `try`/`finally` block in an `async` function).

Comment: Thank you for the advice - especially about the `finally` that indeed solves my problem cleanly. I am glad anyway about the information about creating the promise, this is good to know. Thanks!